# Unable to Install VirtualBox Guest Additions in Kali

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

I am experiencing errors while trying to install Virtualbox Guest Additions on a fresh install of Kali Linux 64-bit. Windows 10 64-bit is the host OS.

1. `apt-get update`
2. `apt-get upgrade -y`
3. `apt-get dist-upgrade -y`
4. `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

After running step 4, the following error appears

```
E: Unable to locate package 'linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64'
```

5. Copied `VBoxGuestAdditions.run` from the mounted `VBOXADDITIONS_5.1.22_1115126` disc to `/root/Desktop`
6. `chmod 755 ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`
7. `./VBoxAdditions.run`

Running step 7 gave the error:

```
vboxadd.sh: Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions.
Failed to set up service vboxadd, please check the log file
/var/log/VBoxGuestAdditions.log for details
```

Inside `/var/log/VBoxGuestAdditions.log`:

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxadd.service ->  /lib/systemd/system/vboxadd.service.
vboxadd.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong.
vboxadd.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong.
vboxadd.sh: failed: modprobe vboxguest failed.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxadd-service.service -> /lib/systemd/system/vboxadd-service.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxadd-x11.service -> /lib/systemd/system/vboxadd-x11.service
```

And inside `/var/log/vboxadd-install.log`:

```
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.header:112: *** ERror: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again. Stop.
Creating user for the Guest Additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.
```

**Before Restart** `uname -a` :

```
 Linux k 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1kali1 (2017-04-04) X86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**After Restart** `uname -a` :

```
Linux k 4.9.0 -kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.25-1kali1 (2017-05-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas what went wrong?

---

**Output of `apt-cache search linux-headers`**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to U&L what is the output of `uname -a` ?

Comment: You might have to reboot before; you might have upgrade the kernel and Linux in runtime still thinks you are using the previous version; OR you should not use Debian backports with kali.

Comment: @GAD3R Output of `uname -a` is `Linux k 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1kali1 (2017-04-04) X86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Restarted Kali, same error. How should I use Debian backports?

Comment: @GAD3R After restarting, `uname -a` outputs `Linux k 4.9.0 -kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.25-1kali1 (2017-05-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache search linux-headers` ?

Comment: @GAD3R Uploaded screenshot of the output in the question. Dont have copy-paste feature without VirtualboxAdditions installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install the appropriate `linux-headers` to your kernel image , get the available `linux-headers` through :

```
apt-cache search linux-headers
```

Then install it:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-amd64
```

Comment: Or just install the meta package `apt-get install linux-headers-amd64` and that will keep your header files up to date during upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a new repository the `sources.list`

Open `sources.list` in `leafpad`:

```
leafpad etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add this line to the file to add the repo:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

then follow your steps.