# uname -r and available linux-headers- packages do not match

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

I am trying to install VirtualBox Guest Additions for guest Kali Rolling.

I get the following outputs:

```
$ uname -r
4.9.0-kali3-amd64

$ dpkg -l | grep linux-headers
ii  linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-all             4.9.30-2kali1                        amd64        All header files for Linux 4.9 (meta-package)
ii  linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-all-amd64       4.9.30-2kali1                        amd64        All header files for Linux 4.9 (meta-package)
ii  linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-amd64           4.9.30-2kali1                        amd64        Header files for Linux 4.9.0-kali4-amd64
ii  linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-common          4.9.30-2kali1                        all          Common header files for Linux 4.9.0-kali4
ii  linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-common-rt       4.9.30-2kali1                        all          Common header files for Linux 4.9.0-kali4-rt
ii  linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-rt-amd64        4.9.30-2kali1                        amd64        Header files for Linux 4.9.0-kali4-rt-amd64
ii  linux-headers-amd64                       4.9+80+kali1                         amd64        Header files for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
```

Why do the kernel versions (`4.9.0-kali3-amd64` vs `4.9.0-kali4-...`) differ and what can I do about it?

---

**SOLUTION**

*Since question is closed I can't add answers. So I'm adding the solution here.*

I tried solutions from the duplicate questions, but they didn't work. Instead, I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxSJpfG-Pn4) which basically suggests following.

Check kernel version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux kali2017 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 ...
```

Currently it contains `kali3`. Install following packages:

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install linux-headers-amd64
$ apt-get install linux-image-4.9.0-kali4-amd64
```

Reboot and check kernel version once again:

```
$ reboot
$ uname -a
Linux kali2017 4.9.0-kali4-amd64 ...
```

Voila, `kali4`! Now, install guest additions:

```
$ apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Done.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363713/unable-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-kali

Answer (score 0):

To install the appropriate linux-headers to your kernel image , get the available linux-headers through :

> apt-cache search linux-headers

Then install it:

> apt-get install linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-amd64